# Почему HTML5 <video> autoplay на смартфонах не работает?

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

Хочу использовать тег `<video>` с параметром `autoplay`,  но на смартфонах не работает. Кроме того на JavaScript метод `.play()` тоже игнорируется на смартфонах.

Очень странно, что на Huawei Honor 8 `autoplay` работает. А на Huawei Honor 8 PRO не работает. На IOS тоже не работает.

Погуглил эту тему, и оказывается, есть ограничения на смартфонах, но тогда непонятно как это [здесь](https://Airforce.com) сделано?

Comment: <video playsinline autoplay loop muted style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" > попробуй

Comment: Не помогает это

Answer (score 0):

Такие теги должны решить проблему:

```html
<video preload="auto" muted playsinline autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
```

Comment: Если более точнее, то muted и playsinline

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не решают.